# get a list of a specific attribute from a list of model objects in a Django template

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to get a list of a specific attribute from a list of model objects, `{{ object_list }}` using the Django Template Language?

Similar to this in Python?
`[o.my_attr for o in object_list]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do list comprehensions inside Django templates. You should do this in your view and pass the list in your context to the template.